# Is there way to run a code every time when any cron is run?

Tags: actions, wp-cron, cron

`publish_post` is an action triggered whenever a post is updated and its new status is "publish".

Is there similar action which is trigger when cron is run including WordPress default crons?

I am building a plugin which logged details about every crons. Something like this cron runs at this time, this crons run at this time, etc..... That's why I need this .

Comment: What would you want to do with this that you can't do with your own cron event?

Comment: I am building a plugin which logged details about every crons. Something like this cron runs at this time, this crons run at this time, etc..... That's why I need this

Answer (score 0):

There is such way, I guess...

When you schedule and event with [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) all you really do is:

> Schedule a hook which will be executed by the WordPress actions core
>   on a specific interval...

And if you'll take a look at `wp-cron.php` then you'll see, that on line 126 this happens:

```
do_action_ref_array( $hook, $v['args'] );
```

### OK... So how does it solve the problem?

It does, because you can use `all` hook. Actions assigned to that hook are called everytime any filter/action is called.

And you can, at least I believe so, use [`wp_next_scheduled`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_next_scheduled) to check, if given hook is event hook or not.